# How to connect opensearch dashboards to SSO AzureAD

Tags: kubernetes-helm, openid, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I'm trying to have SSO in opensearch-dashboards via openid to AzureAD.

Overally - there is no need to have an encrypted communication between opensearch and nodes, there is no need to have encrypted communication between dashboards and master pod. All I need is to have working SSO to Azure AD to see dashboards.

I got errors in dashboards pod like: `"res":{"statusCode":302,"responseTime":746,"contentLength":9}` and `tags":["error","plugins","securityDashboards"],"pid":1,"message":"OpenId authentication failed: Error: [index_not_found_exception] no such index [_plugins], with { index=\"_plugins\"  │ │ & resource.id=\"_plugins\" & resource.type=\"index_expression\" & index_uuid=\"_na_\" }"}` and the browser tells me `The page isn’t redirecting properly`

With last try I got from the ingress pod the error: `Service "default/opensearch-values-opensearch-dashboards" does not have any active Endpoint.`

I really appreciate any advice what am I missing...

I use helm installation of opensearch to AWS EKS (with nginx-controller ingress to publish the adress)

In AD I have an app registered like `https://<some_address>/auth/openid/login`

Here are my actual helm values:

opensearch.yaml

```
---
clusterName: "opensearch-cluster"
nodeGroup: "master"
masterService: "opensearch-cluster-master"
roles:
  - master
  - ingest
  - data
  - remote_cluster_client
replicas: 3
minimumMasterNodes: 1
majorVersion: ""
global:
  dockerRegistry: "<registry>"
opensearchHome: /usr/share/opensearch
config:
  log4j2.properties: |
    rootLogger.level = debug
      
  opensearch.yml: |
    cluster.name: opensearch-cluster
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    plugins.security.disabled: true
    plugins:
      security:
        ssl:
          transport:
            pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
            pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
            pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
            enforce_hostname_verification: false
          http:
            enabled: false
            pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
            pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
            pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
        allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
        allow_default_init_securityindex: true
        authcz:
          admin_dn:
            - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test,C=de
        audit.type: internal_opensearch
        enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
        check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
        restapi:
          roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
        system_indices:
          enabled: true
          indices:
            [
              ".opendistro-alerting-config",
              ".opendistro-alerting-alert*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-results*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-detector*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-checkpoints",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-detection-state",
              ".opendistro-reports-*",
              ".opendistro-notifications-*",
              ".opendistro-notebooks",
              ".opendistro-asynchronous-search-response*",
            ]
extraEnvs: []
envFrom: []
secretMounts: []
hostAliases: []
image:
  repository: "opensearchproject/opensearch"
  tag: ""
  pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
podAnnotations: {}
labels: {}
opensearchJavaOpts: "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "100Mi"
initResources: {}
sidecarResources: {}
networkHost: "0.0.0.0"
rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountAnnotations: {}
  serviceAccountName: ""
podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: true
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim
      - emptyDir
persistence:
  enabled: true
  enableInitChown: true
  labels:
    enabled: false
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 8Gi
  annotations: {}
extraVolumes: []
extraVolumeMounts: []
extraContainers: []
extraInitContainers:
  - name: sysctl
    image: docker.io/bitnami/bitnami-shell:10-debian-10-r199
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -ec
      - |
        CURRENT=`sysctl -n vm.max_map_count`;
        DESIRED="262144";
        if [ "$DESIRED" -gt "$CURRENT" ]; then
            sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144;
        fi;
        CURRENT=`sysctl -n fs.file-max`;
        DESIRED="65536";
        if [ "$DESIRED" -gt "$CURRENT" ]; then
            sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536;
        fi;
    securityContext:
      privileged: true  
priorityClassName: ""
antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
antiAffinity: "soft"
nodeAffinity: {}
topologySpreadConstraints: []
podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
enableServiceLinks: true
protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300
service:
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  headless:
    annotations: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  nodePort: ""
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""
updateStrategy: RollingUpdate
maxUnavailable: 1
podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000
securityConfig:
  enabled: true
  path: "/usr/share/opensearch/plugins/opensearch-security/securityconfig"
  actionGroupsSecret:
  configSecret:
  internalUsersSecret:
  rolesSecret:
  rolesMappingSecret:
  tenantsSecret:
  config:
    securityConfigSecret: ""
    dataComplete: true
    data:
      config.yml: |-
        config:
          dynamic:
            authc:
              basic_internal_auth_domain:
                description: "Authenticate via HTTP Basic"
                http_enabled: true
                transport_enabled: true
                order: 1
                http_authenticator:
                  type: "basic"
                  challenge: false
                authentication_backend:
                  type: "internal"
              openid_auth_domain:
                order: 0
                http_enabled: true
                transport_enabled: true
                http_authenticator:
                  type: openid
                  challenge: false
                  config:
                    enable_ssl: true
                    verify_hostnames: false
                    subject_key: preferred_username
                    roles_key: roles
                    openid_connect_url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<ms_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
                authentication_backend:
                  type: noop
      roles_mapping.yml: |-
        all_access
          reserved: false
          backend_roles:
          - "admin"
          description: "Maps admin to all_access"
terminationGracePeriod: 120
sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144
readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 2000
schedulerName: ""
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  path: /
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
masterTerminationFix: false
lifecycle: {}
keystore: []
networkPolicy:
  create: false
  http:
    enabled: false
fsGroup: ""
sysctl:
  enabled: false
plugins:
  enabled: false
  installList: []
extraObjects: []
```

opensearch-dashboards.yaml

```
---
opensearchHosts: "http://opensearch-cluster-master:9200"
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: "<registry>"
  tag: "1.3.1"
  pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
serviceAccount:
  create: true
  annotations: {}
  name: ""
rbac:
  create: true
secretMounts: []
podAnnotations: {}
extraEnvs: []
envFrom: []
extraVolumes: []
extraVolumeMounts: []
extraInitContainers: ""
extraContainers: ""
podSecurityContext: {}
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000
config:
  opensearch_dashboards.yml: |
    opensearch_security.cookie.secure: false
    opensearch_security.auth.type: openid
    opensearch_security.openid.client_id: <client_id>
    opensearch_security.openid.client_secret: <client_secret>
    opensearch_security.openid.base_redirect_url: https://<some_aws_id>.elb.amazonaws.com
    opensearch_security.openid.connect_url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MS id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
        
    
priorityClassName: ""
opensearchAccount:
  secret: ""
  keyPassphrase:
    enabled: false
labels: {}
hostAliases: []
serverHost: "0.0.0.0"
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 5601
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  nodePort: ""
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  httpPortName: http
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: chart-example.local
            servicePort: 80
  tls: []
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
updateStrategy:
  type: "Recreate"
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}
extraObjects: []
```